# Cannot modify value when user autocomplete google api

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code

`html:
input type='text' name='Address_A' id='Address_1' placeholder='Nhập địa chỉ' autocomplete='off'`

```
javascript:
var input = document.getElementById("Address_1");
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, { types:['geocode'] });

            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {

                var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                input.value = name;
            });
```

but textbox is not show incorrect. Something wrong?

Comment: var place = autocomplete.getPlace() ;
               input.value = name;

where is the variable `name`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try on Google API doc 
The link is here with demo

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

Cheers :D